# How to add Bearer token in API rerquest using Rest Assured

Tags: java

This is a line of code where I want to add "Bearer and then id token from another class file which name is config and id is static variable

request.header("Authorization", ""+CONFIG.id+"");

I want to pass like this
("Authorization", "Bearer etytydfgdddddddddddddddddddddddd");
id is a static variable where token is already store but I want to pass token type as well before token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Exampe {
    private static final String TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9";
    private static final String BASE_URI = "https://mywebsite.com";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.given()
                .baseUri(BASE_URI)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + TOKEN)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get("resource");
    }
}
```

Log:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://mywebsite.com/resource
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Authorization=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the token using the auth().oauth2(token) method. This way, you won't have to explicitly use "Authorization" and "Bearer" text. Rest Assured will do the job. Refer the code below:

```
public class HowToSendBearerToken {
    private static final String myToken = "enter_your_token_value_here";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.given()
                .auth().oauth2(myToken)
                .when()
                .get("end_point");
    }
}
```